# How can I test stored procedure errors in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that runs fine in SQL Server.

I call it in C# like so (with r being the first row):

```
DateTime beginDate = new DateTime(2016, 5, 1);
DateTime? endDate = new DateTime(2016, 5, 31);

this.getDailySalesTableAdapter.Fill(myDataSet.getDailySales, beginDate, endDate);
MessageBox.Show(rMSDataSet.getDailySales.Count.ToString()) ;  //SHOWS 8549 ROWS

MYDataSet.getDailySalesRow r = myDataSet.getDailySales.First();
string mb = "";

// error here---->>>            
foreach (DataColumn dc in r.ItemArray)
{
    if (r[dc] != null) // This will check the null values also 
    {
        mb = mb + r[dc] + " ";
    }

    MessageBox.Show(mb);
}
```

It compiles fine but the runtime error I get on DC is

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Data.DataColumn'

In SQL Server, my stored procedure starts:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getDailySales] 
    @begindate date, 
    @enddate date
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: I would say ItemArray has strings...

Comment: instead of doing `Nullable` DateTime in .net why not default the `enddate` on the Stored procedure = Null also what does the rest of the stored procedure look like.. also the error is pretty straight forward..

Comment: It is a strange arrangement, can I ask what does r.ItemArray contain? You problem is coming of "r[dc]" which is an object and you are trying to add it to string. May I also advise for you to use a stringbuilder? var mb= new StringBuilder(); and in your loop you would go mb.Append([string]);

Comment: The error is on the FOREACH.  r.ItemArray contains the first row of the dataset which the first column contains text and the rest of the columns contain numbers.  I will use the string builder.  I will use the stringbuilder.  Much classier solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would imagine that your problem is that `r.ItemArray` contains strings and not `DataColumn` objects. I came to this conclusion because `foreach (DataColumn dc in r.ItemArray)` is the only place I can see where you are trying to cast an object to a DataColumn.

It looks like r.ItemArray is probably an `object[]` (from looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray(v=vs.110).aspx). So if you are wanting to just get all the values out of this you can just loop through it and look at each value.

The following code should do roughly what you want, I think. Stringbuilder idea credited to KonB from comments. It will also print out `(null)` when it encounters null fields (just skipping them might be confusing when trying to work out what values are from what columns.

```
var mb= new StringBuilder();
foreach (object dataItem in r.ItemArray)
{
    if (dataItem != null) // This will check the null values also 
    {
        mb.Append(dataItem.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        mb.Append("(null)");        
    }
    mb.Append(" ");
}
MessageBox.Show(mb.ToString());
```

Comment: You are right - the foreach is where the error is.  I'm still not sure what the solution is.

Comment: I've updated my answer to hopefully explain and show what you need to do.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`DataColumn.ColumnName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnname(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in r.ItemArray)
{
   if (r[dc] != null) // This will check the null values also 
   {
       mb = mb + r[dc.ColumnName] + " ";  //Updated
   }
   MessageBox.Show(mb);
}
```

Comment: You may be right but it didn't solve the problem.  I just edited my question, the bug is in the FOREACH statement.

Comment: I am not sure for type of `r.ItemArray` . could you check is there property for columns in `r` i.e like `r.Columns`

Comment: There is no property r.Columns.  MessageBox.Show(rMSDataSet.getDailySales.Count.ToString()) ;   = 8549 so there are records there.